# Magento 2 authorize.net alert click on palce order button

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net

I have added the extra filed after credit card filed.

We want to custom validate the extra filed or simply any alert on click of palace order button.

We used **validate** method on **authorizenet-directpost.js** but not working.

**authorizenet-directpost.js**

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/iframe',
         "mage/validation"
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';


        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Authorizenet/payment/authorizenet-directpost',
                customerPoNumber: '',
                timeoutMessage: 'Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.'
            },
            placeOrderHandler: null,
            validateHandler: null,

             initObservable: function () {

                    this._super()
                            .observe(
                                    ['customerPoNumber'

                                    ]
                                    );
                    return this;
                },
                    getData: function () {
                    return {
                        "method": this.item.method,
                         "additional_data": {
                            'po_no': this.customerPoNumber(),

                        }
                    };
                },
           validate: function () {  //My custom valiadte method but not working.
         alert("On click Place order Button");

                },


            /**
             * @param {Object} handler
             */
            setPlaceOrderHandler: function (handler) {
                 return false;
                this.placeOrderHandler = handler;
            },

            /**
             * @param {Object} handler
             */
            setValidateHandler: function (handler) {
                this.validateHandler = handler;
            },

            /**
             * @returns {Object}
             */
            context: function () {
                return this;
            },

            /**
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            isShowLegend: function () {
                return true;
            },

            /**
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getCode: function () {
                return 'authorizenet_directpost';
            },

            /**
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            isActive: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Please help on above issue.
Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.Thanks